# jQuery RTE that's Draggable and Resizable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-resizable, rte

I'm trying to implement http://code.google.com/p/lwrte/issues/list .. I particularly like this jquery text editor because it offers font options, text color, hyperlinking

I want it to be resizable and draggable.  I got draggable and resizable working just fine by making a container div for the the text editor, and having the draggable and the resizable performed on that container div.

However, for whatever reason, the text editor overflows outside the container div no matter what height or width I give the container div.  Text editor width is set to 100%.

My hunch is that the toolbar is messing this up but what do I know!

If this just seems too hard to answer without a code example, I'll try to jsfiddle something up.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turned out that the jquery rte plugin didn't set the height of it's container div ... so once that was tweaked ... all good!

I also turned off the drawing of the resize div because it was buggy

```
$(textarea).wrap($('<div></div>').addClass('rte-zone').width(this.width).height(this.height));      
//$('<div class="rte-resizer"><a href="#"></a></div>').insertAfter(textarea);
```

These are lines 67 and 68 in jquery.rte.js

adding .height(this.height) on line 67 passes the height parameter you give in init
commenting out line 68 removes the resizing

Hope this helps someone else!